# NetBeans: Creating an Action object and attach it to one or more components on a form by IDE tools

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, action, generated-code

Because there is of no use manually edit the automatically Generated Code, how can I creat an Action object and attach this action to one or more components on a form?

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click on the component, like a button
- in the pop-up menu select `Events -> [Type of Event] -> method`. Eg. `Events -> Action -> actionPerformed`
- Then you will see auto-generated code like

  ```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.events.ActionEvent evt) {
      // write your code here
  }
  ```
- Netbeans will auto-generate the adding of a listener to the component, in the uneditable `initComonents()` that you can see.

---

If you have a custom `Action` class, you can always, in your GUI class constructor, add the `Action` object to the component right after the `initComponents()`